# Python best practice for long initialization methods

Tags: python

I need to read a fairly long config file with circa 75 config settings (and it is expected to get more in future).

This leads to a very long initialization method which feels all wrong and looks very ugly:

```
def __params_to_dict(self):
    config = {
        "general": {},
        "site": {"reference": {}},
        "routing": {},
        "sorting": {}, "junction_boxes": {},
        "table": {"tracker_config": {}}
    }

    config["general"]["client"] = self._client_name.get()
    config["general"]["location"] = self._project_location.get()

    config["site"]["ac_cable_fixed_correction"] = self._ac_fixed_allowance.get()
    config["site"]["ac_cable_variable_correction"] = self._ac_var_allowance.get()
    config["site"]["architecture"] = self.__get_architect_string()
    config["site"]["combiner_prefix"] = self._combiner_prefix.get()
    config["site"]["dc_cable_fixed_correction"] = self._conduit_fixed_allowance.get()
    config["site"]["dc_cable_variable_correction"] = self._conduit_var_allowance.get()
    config["site"]["dc_cable_fixed_correction"] = self._dc_fixed_allowance.get()
    config["site"]["dc_cable_variable_correction"] = self._dc_var_allowance.get()
    config["site"]["frequency"] = self._frequency.get()
    config["site"]["inverter_prefix"] = self._inverter_prefix.get()
    config["site"]["pcu_prefix"] = self._pcu_prefix.get()
    config["site"]["pf"] = self._power_factor.get()
    config["site"]["reference"]["x"] = self._reference_x.get()
    config["site"]["reference"]["y"] = self._reference_y.get()
    config["site"]["row_bearing"] = self._row_bearing.get()
    config["site"]["string_prefix"] = self._string_prefix.get()

    config["routing"]["seq"] = re.findall(r"\w+", self._sequence.get())
    config["routing"]["cables_per_conduit"] = self._cables_per_conduit.get()
    config["routing"]["corridor_offset"] = self._corridor_offset.get()
    config["routing"]["direct_to_jb"] = self._direct_to_jb.get()
    config["routing"]["down_pile_offset"] = self._down_pile_offset.get()
    config["routing"]["jb_setback"] = self._jb_setback.get()
    config["routing"]["straight_trench"] = self._straight_trench.get()
    config["routing"]["multi_trench"] = self._multi_trench.get()
    config["routing"]["seq"] = self._sequence.get()
    config["routing"]["trench_depth"] = self._trench_depth.get()

    config["sorting"]["block"] = self._blocks.get()
    config["sorting"]["even_inputs"] = self._even_inputs.get()
    config["sorting"]["even_jbs"] = self._even_jbs.get()
    config["sorting"]["fill"] = self._fill.get().lower()

    ...
```

Clearly difficult to read.  I could add comments identifying each section eg `# general`, `# site` etc. but this also does not make it look any better.  The alternative would be to have separate functions for the separate sections eg `def __general_to_dict`, `def __site_to_dict()` etc.  but I would still end up with an unwieldy class.

What is the best practice?

Edit:  Just to clarify, the front-end here is `tkinter`, so I cannot use `yaml.load()` and `yaml.dump()` which would have made it much cleaner.  I need to to do a `get` and `set` on each variable since they are instances of `tkinter` variable class eg `StringVar()` and `IntVar()`.

Comment: Is it really necessary to rename the config options, like changing `_ac_fixed_allowance` to `ac_cable_fixed_correction`? It seems simpler to leave the names the same, and saves you having to maintain two different sets of documentation.

Comment: Even if it is necessary, you could just create an intermediate lookup table that contains maps from `_ac_fixed_allowance` to `ac_cable_fixed_correction`.

Comment: It's a bit strange to have a class with so many members in the first place. Do they *truly* need to be part of a single class? If rearchitecturing your classes is a bit too lengthy a solution, there's always good old `getattr(self, "_fill")` reflection-esque magic.

Comment: Better still, store the config file as a JSON object in the required format, and just write `config = json.loads(...)`.

Comment: Why does nearly everything have a `.get()`? And can some of the rarer cases, e.g. `.get().lower()` be simplified to a single `.get()`? Or perhaps introduce a new method, `.config()` which returns a nice JSON-serializable structure with the `.lower()` applied? That way, each property is responsible for its own serialization.

Comment: So this is a tkinter front end, hence the `.get()` after each.  Also makes the use of json tricky as suggested.  The config is actually in a `yaml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, this is a question that does not have a single precise answer.
I think the thing that irks you is that you have a form of duplication, where the config and the init are coupled and mirrored.

It might be worthwhile to experiment with yaml config files, which you can read in with PyYaml. The structure you set at the config level is translated into a dictionary and you save the individual read-ins. The dunder init can then be used to set additional logic, such as triggering other initialisations dependent on the setting of some of the fields.

Comment: Actually the config file is a `yaml` file.  Problem is the front end is tkinter and hence not straight forward to just do a `yaml.load()` and `yaml.dump()` since the variable types are tkinter classes such as `IntVar()`  and `StringVar()` that needs to be set via `.set()` and retrieved via `.get()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ideas for data formats that might be useful:

```
self._attr_paths = {
    "_client_name":         ["general", "client"],
    "_project_location":    ["general", "location"],
    "_reference_x":         ["site", "reference", "x"],
    "_reference_y":         ["site", "reference", "y"],
    "_sequence":            ["routing", "seq"],
    ...
}

self._attr_post_get = {
    "_sequence":            lambda x: re.findall(r"\w+", x),
    "_fill":                lambda x: x.lower(),
    ...
}
```

These can be used to generalize serialization in the following manner:

```
def set_path(config, path, value):
    head, *tail = path
    if len(tail) == 0:
        config[head] = value
        return
    if head not in config:
        config[head] = {}            
    set_path(config[head], path, value)

def __params_to_dict(self):
    config = {}
    
    for attr, path in self._attr_paths.items():
        post_get = self._attr_post_get.get(attr, lambda x: x)
        value = post_get(getattr(self, attr))
        set_path(config, path, value)
```

Comment: Thanks Mateen, looks like and interesting option.  I will explore and see if it will work.  I will still not get away without having to physically list all config settings in some way somewhere in the code.  Which I guess is just the consequence of `tkinter`'s implementation.